# Problems with Kendo Grid Hierarchy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Can anyone please write simple steps to implement hierarchy in kendo ui grid (mvc). I have been trying their demos but cannot get it working. thanks a lottt for your help!

I think I am missing something but here is what i am doing (as on http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/hierarchy.html)

I am adding a .ClientDetailTemplateId("Grid2Template") into my existing grid.
Then I am writing code for above Grid2Template.

I am doing 100% of what is shown in the demo but cannot get it to work with these two steps. Is there anything extra involved?

Here is a very simple demo project... http://www.mediafire.com/?5qjyp40qfef7dkb

Comment: Can show some if the code you have?

Comment: thanks for your help. I am really looking for it. please see the link to a demo

Comment: i have edited the question and added a link to demo. thanks!

Comment: FYI, the answer marked as the solution is the worst thing you can do. If I could downvote it multiple times, I would.

For anyone looking at this now, the fix I posted at the bottom of this link has now been included in the Kendo UI code, so you should no longer be having this problem as of Q3 2013.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is kinda tricky and hard to find. Go to the webconfig and remove the following line:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="4.5" targetFramework="4.5" encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

This encoder AntiXSS mangles the client template and the Grid is unable to display the detail template.

The project should run fine after this change.

Comment: You are genius mate :). I spent hours and hours on this. Thank you so much for your time and effort. It has really been a relief. thanks!!!

Comment: So have you looked into what part of AntiXSS is causing this issue? Is there a better way around it (turn off validate request or output your template as raw html to bypass xss filtering?) ... Here is to hoping you did not disable this on any production application of any significance!

Comment: Holy crap! I can't believe this is the solution.  Though it worked for me, what's the consequences of having turned that off?

Comment: This is definitely not an appropriate way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry to be late to the party.  There is no need to remove the AntiXss encoder. Simply decode the string Kendo spits out and display it raw on your view.

So instead of:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip().Items(…).ToClientTemplate())
```

Do this:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.Kendo().TabStrip().Items(…).ToClientTemplate().ToString()))
```

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** FYI Telerik has included my solution into Kendo UI MVC as of Q1 2014, so if you are on newer bits, you no longer need these "solutions".

---

Taking out the AntiXssEncoder is definitely bad news, and you should not do it. I tried working with Jportelas' and Marcelo's answers, but they still did not completely solve the problem. When dealing with required fields, Kendo & MVC inject the required field validator into the javascript, which has the spaces encoded in a totally different way (it uses the escaped UTF-8 string that represents the ampersand, followed by the html character code for the pound sign. Together they represent a space. Pretty screwed up, right?!?)

[I've created a Gist](https://gist.github.com/advancedrei/5724537) that shows how to solve the problem for any control, not just Kendo UI. I've also asked Telerik to include the solution in the next release... please feel free to do the same.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

One clever co-worker of mine found something similar, he found that spaces where replaced by " " in the client template generated string so he is doing this and it works:

```
@Html.Raw((Html.Kendo().Grid<..>...ToClientTemplate()..ToHtmlString().Replace("&#32;", " ")))
```

We didn't want to disable AntiXSS since it will be like putting down your defenses.